# Comparing arrays in WP_Query with custom fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having an issue with comparing values between two arrays in wp_query

I have the two roles administrator and forhandler_salg ($roles returns an array with these two values), but it only queries posts with the "public" key set to true

I got more posts when I changed the "allowed_userroles" key compare value to "LIKE", but those aren't the right posts

```
$roles = "";

if (is_user_logged_in()) {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    $roles = (array) $user->roles;
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'downloads',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'public',
            'value' => true,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        # Not working
        array(
            'key' => 'allowed_userroles',
            'value' => $roles,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
```

print_r($args) returns

```
    Array
(
    [post_type] => downloads
    [posts_per_page] => -1
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => OR
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => public
                    [value] => 1
                    [compare] => =
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => allowed_userroles
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [16] => administrator
                            [17] => forhandler_salg
                        )

                    [compare] => IN
                )

        )

)
```

And a post with the "public" custom field as true and some added roles returns this, when I print_r() the allowed_userroles for the post:

```
Array
(
    [0] => role1
    [1] => role2
    [2] => role3
)
```

How would I go about checking if allowed_userroles in the query has values that are also present in $roles?

EDIT: "like" works if I put in a role manually

Comment: Have you tried splitting the values in `$roles` and adding each of them  to the meta query?

Comment: @TPaone Hmm, I just tried doing it with implode and it seems to work, but it's repeating 21 times, seemingly once for each post, after I replaced the $roles variable with the imploded variable

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines where the query would look more like `public ="true" OR allowed_userroles LIKE "%Role1%" OR allowed_userroles LIKE "%Role2%"`. I assume the `allowed_userroles` field is storing a comma-separated string?

Comment: Ohhh, problem is that its a dynamic custom field, so I wouldn't be able to hard code it, and LIKE wouldn't be good enough because it would return any posts that contain the word from the role + more added to it

Also seems like it didn't work (from my first comment), it just repeats once for each post

Comment: Yeah, I get that. You'd just explode the array of roles and then add each one as a separate meta_query condition. With regards to the number of results, that may be a case of the OR conditional returning true. You may need to add a query monitor plugin to review the SQL syntax and check if the generated syntax matches expectation.  When in doubt, you could always use `$wpdb` and build your own query.

Comment: Do you have an example of this being done? I'm not used to doing more advanced meta queries. The query monitor plugin outputs it as "OR ( wpwj_postmeta.meta_key = 'allowed_userroles'
AND wpwj_postmeta.meta_value IN ('administrator','forhandler_salg') ) )"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for these kinds of problems, it's easier to start with your basic array of arguments and then modify it.

Since this question is tagged with ACF, ACF is likely storing this as a single meta entry. Furthermore, if this is an array of values, ACF is very likely storing it as a serialized PHP string in the database (e.g., `a:2:{i:0;s:4:"1234";i:1;s:3:"qed";}`).

Let's start with the base code:

```
$roles = [];

if (is_user_logged_in()) {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = (array) $user->roles;
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'downloads',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'public',
            'value' => "1",
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);
```

In this case, you'll need to use a `LIKE` to attempt a sub-string match.

```
foreach($roles as $role) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = [
        'key' => 'allowed_userroles',
        'value' => $role, // can't remember if wp will wrap value with %
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ];
}
```

Ideally, you'd want to match based on the string length as well, but that might be a bit prohibitive. If you keep running into issues getting the exact results out, you could run two separate queries. The first query would be for all public items, and the second query would be for non-public items. You could then take the results of the second query and then filter out values that do not have the correct meta, since it'll be easier to process using `get_field('allowed_userroles')`.

Comment: This seems to do the job, thanks so much!